# Snippet usefulness - Function.prototype.call.bind(Function.prototype.bind)

Tags: javascript, code-snippets

I saw an [article](https://variadic.me/posts/2013-10-22-bind-call-and-apply-in-javascript.html) about this javascript snippet:

```
var binder = Function.prototype.call.bind(Function.prototype.bind);
```

This snippet turns: `var fBound = f.bind(context);` into: `var fBound = binder(f,context);`
But i'm wondering about usefulness of it. As it could be seen this snippet does not make code shorter and gives new function binder() that replaces standard bind(), that makes code more difficult to read cause programmer needs to keep in mind new function.

Could you provide a real need in this snipped that I have probably missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the blog post, there is no 'usefulness' except syntactic sugar, turning:

```
slice.call([1,2,3], 0, 1);
slice.apply([1,2,3], [0,1]);
```

to

```
slice([1,2,3], 0, 1);
```

The change allows to pass proper `this` context as the first argument of the function without explicitly calling `call` and `apply`.